# maximum subarray of an array with integers

Tags: algorithm

In an interview one of my friends was asked to find the subarray of an array with maximum sum, this my solution to the problem , how can I improve the solution make it more optimal , should i rather consider doing in a recursive fashion ?

```
def get_max_sum_subset(x):
        max_subset_sum = 0
        max_subset_i = 0
        max_subset_j = 0
        for i in range(0,len(x)+1):
            for j in range(i+1,len(x)+1):
                current_sum = sum(x[i:j])
                if current_sum > max_subset_sum:
                    max_subset_sum = current_sum
                    max_subset_i = i
                    max_subset_j = j
        return max_subset_sum,max_subset_i,max_subset_j
```

Comment: No, you should try to find an O(N) solution.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

Your solution is O(n^2). The optimal solution is linear. It works so that you scan the array from left to right, taking note of the best sum and the current sum:

```
def get_max_sum_subset(x):
    bestSoFar = 0
    bestNow = 0
    bestStartIndexSoFar = -1
    bestStopIndexSoFar = -1
    bestStartIndexNow = -1
    for i in xrange(len(x)):
        value = bestNow + x[i]
        if value > 0:
            if bestNow == 0:
                bestStartIndexNow = i
            bestNow = value
        else:
            bestNow = 0

        if bestNow > bestSoFar:
            bestSoFar = bestNow
            bestStopIndexSoFar = i
            bestStartIndexSoFar = bestStartIndexNow

    return bestSoFar, bestStartIndexSoFar, bestStopIndexSoFar
```

This problem was also discussed thourougly in [Programming Pearls: Algorithm Design Techniques](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0201657880) (highly recommended). There you can also find a recursive solution, which is not optimal (O(n log n)), but better than O(n^2).

Comment: What if the max array can contain negative values (and they aren't changed to 0)? I.e. [3, -1, 5, -6, -9] max is [3, -1, 5]. Same O(N) algorithm as above, or does it need tweaks?

Comment: This algorithm handles that case.

Comment: Thanks, I put the C implementation here: https://gist.github.com/3019861

Comment: there is an O(n) solution, I was asked to do this on an interview and I bombed it...

Comment: Yep, this one is O(n) (=linear).

Comment: unfortunately, provided algorithm is wrong, debug it for {4, -1, -5, 10, 2, -1, 7, -2} and you'll see how many mistake it does. Basically it finds only maximum element and its position

Comment: dmytrivv, what do you mean? For that input this algorithm returns (18, 3, 6), i.e. summing elements 10, 2, -1 and 7 gives the highest sum of 18. What's the correct solution in your opinion?

Comment: @Antti Nice answer. I was solving a similar question, which asks to find the maximum subarray sum in a circular array. Do you think the same approach would work? We can add just this condition in the top loop as terminating condition -  (i < n || (i < 2n && i mod n < bestStartIndex)) and replace x[i] with x[i mod n]

Comment: Nitin Garg, yep, that should work well for circular arrays.

Comment: This solution doesn't work for an array with all negative numbers.  For example, given [ -1 , -2 ] this solution will return 0 as the best sum.

Comment: @Chris, you're right, good catch. After quick thinking not sure what's a good way of fixing the algorithm.

Comment: The link is broken

Comment: Thanks @david_adler, I updated the link now.

Comment: This doesn't work for array of all negative integers,

Answer (score 18):

This is a well-known problem that displays *overlapping optimal substructure*, which suggests a dynamic programming (DP) solution. Although DP solutions are usually quite tricky (I think so at least!), this one is a great example to get introduced to the whole concept.

The first thing to note is that the maximal subarray (which must be a contiguous portion of the given array A) ending at position j either consists of the maximimal subarray ending at position j-1 plus A[j], or is empty (this only occurs if A[j] < 0). In other words, we are asking whether the element A[j] is contributing positively to the current maximum sum ending at position j-1. If yes, include it in the maximal subarray so far; if not, don't. Thus, from solving smaller subproblems that overlap we can build up an optimal solution.

The sum of the maximal subarray ending at position j can then be given recursively by the following relation:

```
sum[0] = max(0, A[0])
sum[j] = max(0, sum[j-1] + A[j])
```

We can build up these answers in a bottom-up fashion by scanning A from left to right. We update sum[j] as we consider A[j]. We can keep track of the overall maximum value and the location of the maximal subarray through this process as well. Here is a quick solution I wrote up in Ruby:

```
def max_subarray(a)
    sum = [0]
    max, head, tail = sum[0], -1, -1
    cur_head = 0

    (0...a.size).each do |j|
        # base case included below since sum[-1] = sum[0]
        sum[j] = [0, sum[j-1] + a[j]].max
        cur_head = j if sum[j-1] == 0
        if sum[j] > max
            max, head, tail = sum[j], cur_head, j
        end
    end

    return max, head, tail
end
```

Take a look at my [gist](https://gist.github.com/pdsouza/0678c4d0823858c49ccdeed8fca44672) if you'd like to test this for yourself.

This is clearly a linear O(N) algorithm since only one pass through the list is required. Hope this helps!

Comment: Though it should probably be `sum[0] = max(0, A[0])` instead of `A[j]`?

Comment: @XiangJi Woops, you're right...I've updated the explanation to match the code. Thanks for catching that!

Comment: This will never work for an array of all negative integers.

Comment: @mhaseeb The maximal subarray of an array with only negative integers is the empty subarray, which my solution will output. I am assuming the empty subarray is allowed as an answer of course; I mentioned this in my description about how the array will be empty for A[j] < 0.

Comment: I don't think you need the check for `sum[j] > 0` because the previous line guarantees this.

Comment: @AramKocharyan Thank you for catching that! Updated.

Answer (score 5):

A much better solution approach can be derived by thinking about what conditions must hold for a maximum-sum sub-array: the first item on either end that is not included (if any) must be negative and the last item on either end that is included must be non-negative. You don't need to consider any other end points for the sub-array except where these changes occur in the original data.

Comment: This is a useful observation but doesn't help to change it from an O(n^2) algorithm.

Comment: @TedHopp Today I saw that the downvote on your answer I had cast in 2013 is the only downvote I ever made and the question/answer wasn't deleted afterwards. Now I came back to see why and I'm not sure. Maybe it's because the solution was incomplete and didn't solve the next step - complexity. Anyway, I managed to unlock the answer and upvote it this time. Now my record is clean and you have a piece of reputation back. Sorry for being so inconsiderate back then.

Comment: @ZoranHorvat - No worries. Thanks for the undownvote! :)

Answer (score 5):

let `n` - elements count, `a(i)` - your array `f(i)` - maximum sum of subarray that ends at position `i` (minimum length is 1). Then:

```
f(0) = a(i);
f(i) = max(f(i-1), 0) + a(i); //f(i-1) when we continue subarray, or 0 - when start at i position
```

`max(0, f(1), f(2), ... , f(n-1))` - the answer

Answer (score 4):

There is a short video from MIT that helps you understand this dynamic programming problem. 
http://people.csail.mit.edu/bdean/6.046/dp/
Click on the first link under the 'problems' section and you will see it.

Answer (score 2):

Here is a simple O(N) algorithm from http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maximum_subarray_problem

```
int maxsofar=0;
int maxendinghere=0;
for i=[0 n] {
    maxendinghere=max(maxendinghere+x[i],0);
    maxsofar=max(maxsofar,maxendinghere);
}
```

Comment: Are you going to quote the wikipedia article you copied this from? Also, last statement belongs in the loop.

Comment: yes it includes  in loop,as first question no copy,from nowhere,i had have dont it many times ,so i know it

Comment: if it is not  zero based,then he/she could create one based  array,no problem

Comment: This is the O(N) algorithm from http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maximum_subarray_problem

Comment: @n.m is it incorrect?or  why ignore it?

Comment: also consider this algorithm from programming pearls,i have this book

Comment: This returns the maximum sum, not the sub-array that OP asked for. It would need to be modified to actually return the subarray.

Comment: I'll vote this up if you state your source and fix your indentation

Comment: it is from programming pearls,i have read it many times and studed it

Comment: See also: http://www.algorithmist.com/index.php/Kadane's_Algorithm

Answer (score 1):

Unless I'm missing something important, if they are positive integers the subset would include the whole array, if they're integers, it would include only positive integers. Is there another constraint there?

Comment: Yes, consider -100, 100, -1, 100, -100. The maximum sum subarray will include -1.

Comment: You are missing something important. The numbers are not necessarily positive. If you include two numbers, you must include everything in between. That's the meaning of `subarray` — arrays are contiguous.

Comment: So a subarray must have contiguous elements, right?

Comment: The elements must be contiguous, otherwise the problem is trivial (all positive elements).

Answer (score 0):

Java solution:

Does not work for an array with all negatives.

```
public static int[] maxsubarray(int[] array) {

    //empty array check

    if (array.length == 0){
        return new int[]{}; 
    }

    int max = 0;
    int maxsofar = 0;

    //indices 

    int maxsofarstart = 0;
    int maxsofarend = 0;
    int maxstartindex = 0;

    for (int i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
        if (array[i] > 0) {

            if (max == 0) {
                maxstartindex = i;
            }

            max = max + array[i];

            if (max > maxsofar) {

                maxsofar = max;
                maxsofarstart = maxstartindex;
                maxsofarend = i;

            }

    } else {
        max = 0;
    }

}

return Arrays.copyOfRange(array, maxsofarstart, maxsofarend + 1);

}
```

Answer (score 0):

here is one of most well-expained, tested, working solution - http://rerun.me/blog/2012/08/30/maximum-continuous-subarray-problem-kandanes-algorithm/

```
package me.rerun;

public class Kadane {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int[] intArr={3, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, 2, 0, 0, 0 };
        //int[] intArr = {-1, 3, -5, 4, 6, -1, 2, -7, 13, -3};
        //int[] intArr={-6,-2,-3,-4,-1,-5,-5};
        findMaxSubArray(intArr);
    }



public static void findMaxSubArray(int[] inputArray){

    int maxStartIndex=0;
    int maxEndIndex=0;
    int maxSum = Integer.MIN_VALUE; 

    int cumulativeSum= 0;
    int maxStartIndexUntilNow=0;

    for (int currentIndex = 0; currentIndex < inputArray.length; currentIndex++) {

        int eachArrayItem = inputArray[currentIndex];

        cumulativeSum+=eachArrayItem;

        if(cumulativeSum>maxSum){
            maxSum = cumulativeSum;
            maxStartIndex=maxStartIndexUntilNow;
            maxEndIndex = currentIndex;
        }
        else if (cumulativeSum<0){
            maxStartIndexUntilNow=currentIndex+1;
            cumulativeSum=0;
        }
    }

    System.out.println("Max sum         : "+maxSum);
    System.out.println("Max start index : "+maxStartIndex);
    System.out.println("Max end index   : "+maxEndIndex);
}

}
```

Answer (score 0):

This is the correct Java Code which will handle scenarios including all negative numbers.

```
public static long[] leftToISumMaximize(int N, long[] D) {
    long[] result = new long[N];
    result[0] = D[0];
    long currMax = D[0];
    for (int i = 1; i < N; i++) {
        currMax = Math.max(D[i], currMax + D[i]);
        result[i] = Math.max(result[i - 1], currMax);
    }
    return result;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I have made a function for a little more general problem:

- Find maximum sum subarray (meaning its bounds and sum, not only the sum)
- If two subarrays have equal sums then pick the shorter one
- If two equally long subarrays have equal sums then pick the one that appears first.

Function is based on Kadane's algorithm and it runs in O(n) time. Basically, this is it:

```
function MaxSumSubarray(a, n, start out, len out)
    -- a - Array
    -- n - Length of the array
    -- start - On output starting position of largest subarray
    -- len - On output length of largest subarray
    -- Returns sum of the largest subarray
begin

    start = 0
    len = 1
    int sum = a[0]

    curStart = 0
    curLen = 1
    curSum = a[0]

    for i = 2 to n
        begin
            if a[i] >= curSum + a[i] then
                begin
                    curStart = i
                    curLen = 1
                    curSum = a[i]
                end
            else
                begin
                    curLen = curLen + 1
                    curSum = curSum + a[i]
                end

            if (curSum > sum) OR
               (curSum = sum AND curLen < len) OR
               (curSum = sum AND curLen = len AND curStart < start) then
               begin
                    start = curStart
                    len = curLen
                    sum = curSum
                end

        end

    return sum

end
```

I've uploaded the whole solution in C#, with analysis and examples, in this article: [Maximum Sum Subarray](http://www.codinghelmet.com/?path=exercises/maximum-subarray)

Answer (score 0):

Not sure but Accepted Solution didn't for work me for all the scenarios (May be I misunderstood it)
So I did small modification, instead of 
    if(value > 0)
I changed it yo 
    if(value > bestNow)

```
.....(I wrote it in Scala)
```

And it is working for the all scenarios

```
def findMaxSubArray(list: List[Int]): (Int, Int, Int) = {

 var (bestNow,bestSoFar) = (0, 0)
 var ( startIndexNow, startIndexSoFar, endIndex) = (-1, -1, -1)

 for (i <- 0 until list.length) {
   var value = bestNow + list(i)
   if (value > bestNow) {
     if (bestNow == 0)
       startIndexNow = i
     bestNow = value
   } else
     bestNow = 0

  if (bestNow > bestSoFar) {
    bestSoFar = bestNow
    startIndexSoFar = startIndexNow
    endIndex = i
    } 
  }

  return (bestSoFar, startIndexSoFar, endIndex)
 }     

 def main(args: Array[String]) {
  println(findMaxSubArray(List(3, -1, 5, 3, -6, -9, 6, 1)).toString)
  println(findMaxSubArray(List(3, -1, 5, 3, -6, -9, 6, 3)).toString)
  println(findMaxSubArray(List(20, -1, 5, 3, -6, -9, 6)).toString)
}

   Output.....
    (max =8, start=2, end=3)
    (max=9, start=6, end=7)
    (max=20, start=0, end= 0)
```