# Issue getting the beginning of a max subarray

Tags: python, algorithm

I am trying to implement a method to get the maxSubArray sum and the associated beginning and end indices.  For reference, the maxSubArray is the contiguous subArray whose integer sum is the largest amongst all subArrays.  I have the sum correct, and the end index correct, but I am having trouble with getting the beginning.  I have accounted for one trivial case, but no matter what I do, I can't seem to account for all of the cases.  Whenever I account for one, another emerges.  Obviously getting the sum is possible in linear time, but I can't seem to figure out a way to get the correct start index efficiently.

```
def maxSubArray(seq):
    #max_i = max ending at i, max_gen = best max up until i
    max_i = max_gen = beg = end = prev_max = 0

    for i in xrange(len(seq)):
        #use dynamic programming to get maxSubArray sum (works)
        max_i = max(0, max_i + seq[i])
        max_gen = max(max_gen, max_i)

        #get correct end (works)
        if prev_max < max_gen:
            end = i

        prev_max = max_gen

    if max_gen == 0:
        max_gen = max(seq)
        beg = end = seq.index(max_gen)

    return [max_gen, beg, end]
```

Like I said, I tried many things, but keep on deleting them as every new way introduces new/old problems.  Anyone have any advice/a solution?  I saw a similar question under the Java tag, but the answers were not correct. For convenience, I have included a brute force method, which I know works, and the mini-tester that I've been using:

```
def bruteForceCheck(seq):
    maxV = [float('-inf'), 0, 0]

    for i in xrange(len(seq)):
        for j in xrange(i,len(seq)):
            if (sum(seq[i:j+1]) > maxV[0]):
                maxV = [sum(seq[i:j+1]), i, j]

    return maxV

if __name__ == "__main__":

    for i in xrange(1000):
        l = []
        for j in xrange(15):
            num = random.randint(-1000,1000)

            #didn't feel like dealing with issue of two methods 
            #choosing to count or not count 0s
            while (num == 0):
                num = random.randint(-1000,1000)

            l.append(num)

        msa = maxSubArray(l)
        bfc = bruteForceCheck(l)

        if msa != bfc:
            print l
            print msa
            print bfc
            break
```

Comment: The only "good" way I came up with was go back from the final `end` and take the sum until I reached the point that had to be the beginning, but I feel like there should be a better way to do this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Forgive me, but this works and is Pythonic.

```
def maxSubArray(seq):
    all_sum = cur_sum = 0
    all_beg = cur_beg = 0
    all_end = 0
    for cur_end, x in enumerate(seq, 1):
        if cur_sum + x > 0:
            cur_sum += x
            if all_sum < cur_sum:
                all_sum = cur_sum
                all_beg, all_end = cur_beg, cur_end
        else:
            cur_sum = 0
            cur_beg = cur_end
    return all_sum, all_beg, all_end
```

The algorithm is the same. There is the sum, beginning index, and end index, for an array ending here (`cur_`) and overall (`all_`).

EDIT: Note that the end index here is exclusive.

Also, if there are multiple optimal subarrays, this returns the first and longest.

Comment: Thank you.  This is exactly what I was looking for.  I had a few things that looked very similar, albeit slightly more complicated and incorrect.  Thanks for clearing that up.

Comment: Yes, the algorithm is in fact the same.

Answer (score 1):

This problem seemed familiar to me ... a quick search turned up a wikipedia article [Maximum subarray problem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maximum_subarray_problem).  Adapated from the c++ solution in that article

```
def maxSubArray(seq):
    max_so_far = seq[0]
    max_ending_here = 0
    begin = 0
    begin_temp = 0
    end = 0
    for i in xrange(1, len(seq)):
        if max_ending_here < 0:
            max_ending_here = seq[i]
            begin_temp = i
        else:
            max_ending_here += seq[i]
        if max_ending_here >= max_so_far:
            max_so_far = max_ending_here
            begin = begin_temp
            end = i
    return max_so_far, begin, end
```

Comment: Hmmm... didn't look far enough down the search results.  Also answered [here on SO](http://stackoverflow.com/a/7943955/2823755).