# How I can print largest sum in this Program?

Tags: java

```
package Message; 
public class Example_R { 
public static void main (String args[])  
    int n=1;
    int input[]={1, 2, 1, 3, 4};         
    for (int j=0; j<=4; j++) {
        int Add = 0;
        for (int i=0; i<=4; i++)    {
           if (input[j] !=input[i]) {
        Add+=input[i];
           }
        }
                System.out.println(Add);
            }
         }
 }
```

Output of This program is: 9 9 9 8 7 sum of all the other elements in the array that are not equal to the element.
Now I want to extend the program so I can print the Largest sum of any of it's element, (In this case 9 is the largest sum.) Do you have any suggestions? For this assignment I am restricted from using additional array, hashmap etc. not allowed. Arrays.sort(..)

Comment: please explain problem properly..Dont understand

Comment: I've seen clearer specifications from my project manager...

Comment: read this :
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7943903/maximum-subarray-of-an-array-with-integers

Comment: You said you can't use an array. `input[]` is an array.

Comment: Sorry additional array

Comment: I would use a for loop and keep current largest value in a variable of type comparable then use the `compareTo()` method, I solved close to the same problem using this method yesterday. - see my answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You probably want to create a separate method that you pass your "input[]" array to (left as an exercise).  However when considering problems like this, first just consider how you would do it in english (or whatever your native language is).  Write down that strategy (an "algorithm") and then implement that in Java.

```
public class Example_R {
public static void main(String args[]) {
    int input[] = { 1, 2, 1, 3, 4 };
    int largestSum = 0;
    int currentSum;

    for (int j = 0; j < input.length; j++) {
        currentSum = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < input.length; i++) {
            if (input[j] != input[i]) {
                currentSum += input[i];
            }
        }
        System.out.println("Sum of all values not equal to " + input[j]
                + " is: " + currentSum);
        if (j == 0) {
            largestSum = currentSum;
        } else {
            if (largestSum < currentSum) {
                largestSum = currentSum;
            }
        }
    }
    System.out.println("The largest overall sum was " + largestSum);
}
}
```

Comment: This program looks fine but it does not give  the output 9 any help

Comment: as Largest sum in this case is 9

Comment: I assume you corrected my original posting to ensure the loops had the correct limit and then printed out the final result.  I made the corrections above.  Did you transform the program into a separate method to return largest sum?

Answer (score 2):

Hint: use a variable that is holding "the largest sum reached so far". You will update it very time you compute a new sum.

You will need to find "how and when do I initialize this variable ?" and "how do I update it ?"

Answer (score 0):

You'll need a temporary variable to save the current highest number.

```
int temp = intArray[0]
for(int i : intArray)
{
if(i > temp)
temp = i;
}
```

Comment: What are you talking about ? "intArray" is the array he is using to sort the values sum of all "the other elements in the array" that are not equal to the element. In his case its called input

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
int n = 1,sum=0;
int[] input = { 1, 2, 1, 3, 4 };
for (int j = 0; j <= 4; j++){
     int Add = 0;
     for (int i = 0; i <= 4; i++){
          if (input[j] != input[i])
              Add += input[i];    
     }
     if (sum < Add)
         sum = Add;
}
```

After completing the second loop every time,the "sum" was updated if it is less than the current "add" value.

Comment: Could you add some additional information, along with your answer?

Comment: After completing the second loop every time,the "sum" was updated if it is less than the current "add" value..

Comment: I added your comment for explanation and formatted your code:)

Answer (score -1):

You can use variables of type `Comparable` and use the `compareTo()` method.

1. `one.compareTo(two)` will return > 0 if `one > two`
2. `one.compareTo(two)` will return < 0 if `one < two`
3. `one.compareTo(two)` will return 0 if `one` and `two` are equal

Go through the array, compare the current index with the previous index, and update a variable that holds the currentLargest value.

Comment: Did not address the prime issue the student was having .. how to keep track of a "largest" sum

Comment: "Go through the array, compare the current index with the previous index, and update a variable that holds the currentLargest value." - that is how you keep track of largest sum. Read before voting.